# Should i develop with CakePHP 2 or 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm just starting on a software as a service project using CakePHP. I can see that version 3 is still in beta and I can see this project taking 3-6 months.

My question is should I start with version 2 or version 3 beta with the latter probably reaching a stable release.

I don't want to learn version 2 and then version 3 has a fair few changes.

Comment: Quite funny for the question to be closed as opinion based exactly 6 months after Cake 3.0.0 was released making the question's answer much more obvious/less opinion based.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** Go for CakePHP 3.0 now if you start a new project. CakePHP 3 is no longer in RC or beta state so it can be used without any doubts now.

---

The question is likely to get closed because it is opinionated, I'm undecided to put up a close vote for that reason myself, however...

Cake3 is in fact OK to be used for a project that is going to take 3-6 month - that is my opinion. But you'll have to expect a few API changes until then. I would not sacrifice the more modern architecture of Cake3 and language features, mostly the namespaces and closures for using an old version that doesn't support them just because Cake3 has not yet reached 3.0 (without the RC).

I've started using Cake myself when 1.3 was in alpha and the transition from 1.2 to 1.3 was pretty smooth. I've had to adept to the API changes during the ongoing development of 1.3 but this was not a game breaker and I never had to spend much time for it.

Same story with Cake3. We are using 2.x and started a new project using Cake3 and don't have much trouble with it. So far it just works fine and the occasional adoptions to the API changes are no game breaker as it was before.

You can see that Cake3 is mostly feature complete by now.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/wiki/3.0-Roadmap

If you go further you'll notice that 3.1 is going to raise the minimum php version to 5.5.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/wiki/3.1-Roadmap

This is because 5.4 is going to reach it's end of support. So there is no reason to support it any more. Based on this you can make your guess when 3.0 will be released: Likely before 5.4 is officially deprecated.

The one and only disadvantage of Cake3 right now might be the availability of plugins. But there are already lots of plugins that are upgraded to 3.0 and even new plugins for 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

**Absolutely 100% go with CakePHP 3.x.**  There should no longer be any debate as Cake 3 is now up and running and no longer in beta or RC...etc.

---

**Original Answer:**

If you're starting now (Jan '15), I see no point in learning CakePHP 2.x.  Why go through the trouble, when by the time your project is complete, you'll already have out-of-date code (I know "out-of-date" might be a bit extreme, but...).

Not only that, but CakePHP2 and CakePHP3 are worlds different with a fairly sizable learning curve.  I cannot imagine, at this point learning one language only to have to re-learn the entire thing in less than a year.

IF CakePHP 3 RC wasn't a viable choice (ie projects crashed all the time, or had issues left and right), and you're on a deadline, then you'd have no choice anyway.  But CakePHP 3 RC seems to be running fine and is already being used on live projects.

**The no-brain answer IMO:  Go with CakePHP 3.**  I certainly would if I were in your shoes.

Answer (score 0):

At this point (19th Jan 2014) , it is safe to go with cakephp 2 . cakephp 3 is not a stable release and there is no clear schedule date for stable release yet. I dont think it will be a breeze to update it later to a stable version if you develop in its current version . You might end up changing lot of code.

Answer (score -4):

Hi I am working with cakephp since 1 year and I found that you can use cakephp 2.x because it is stable version don't need to extra configuration but in cakphp 3 is unstable version  you install the composer in cakephp 3 & the structure of cakephp 3 is totally different form cakephp2 such as cakephp2 root folder is APP but cakphp 3 there is no app folder its contains src, bin, vendor etc

Comment: I agree that for regular CakePHP 2 programmers, CakePHP 3 might be presenting a learning curve, but for a fresher why to advice an older version? They can directly get on with CakePHP 3.

Comment: At the time this answer was posted it was IMO valid advice - 3.x was not a stable release, and documentation (whilst pretty darn good) was still being written. Times have changed now, 3.x is stable, the docs are complete and most importantly - new users are not having major problems learning 3.x.

Answer (score -7):

**I found too many problems width cakephp 3.1** :

1. In **appController**, the function **beforeFilter()** is not working well as it was in **cakephp 2.x**, **when I tape return false It should return a blank page** but now It returns everything like if this function **beforeFilter()** in the **appController** is not controling nothing.
2. In **Model**, the functions **beforeFilter(), beforeSave() and beforeDelete()** have been replaced with too many functions in cakephp 3.1 but in reality those functions are not realy usefull, for the simple reason these functions don't work as we expected them to work, there is no centralization of these functions, you can say those new functions are not working at all.
3. **The system of prefix** and **how we can contrôl access to some users to access to Admin/ prefix for example only from the controller** and **all the liberty this great functions** of **cakephp 2.x** can give us now all this is gone with **cakephp 3.1** and there are some bad restrictions you should respect.
4. cakephp 3.1 error managing are not helping you at all to found the source of the problem, it's like you're working with no compiler you found the source of the problem yourself, an if it's an very big project I garenty for you that you can failed at 60%....

too many reasons push you to wait for an other stable version of cakephp 3.x to start using this technologie.

Comment: This is **not** a problem of the framework. Honestly, it seems you're incapable or unwilling of reading the migration guide and understanding the reasons for the changes. Nothing you describe here is a bug and works as intended and was changed for a good reason. Prefix routing and the according auth adapter are still there. You don't even understand that 3.x *is* a stable release. Lookup "Semver". If you can't master your project and blame the framwork you might think about switching the profession to something else or start learning.

Comment: `I don't want to learn version 2 and then version 3` The OP at the time of asking (9 months ago), had no experience of CakePHP 2 or 3 - Everything you mention here relates to migrating and isn't relevant to the question, and is not helpful to readers. I don't think you will find waiting for future releases to help with you, what you list as problems are _all_ misunderstandings (some bigger than others - like thinking Model::beforeFilter is a thing) - Cake 3.x is already stable, and isn't going to change in ways that you think it should.