# cakePHP 2.x or 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-3.0

Hi I just started learning cakePHP framework and noticed that there are two versions on development: 2.x and 3.x . May I know what the differences are between the two and which one is better on which categories? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid this question is likely to be closed due to it being a question that is open to opinions, have a look at the help center to help improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: *throws an opinion* Go with 3.x, it's the future. Also you'd better consult Dr. Google with such questions first. **https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cakephp+3+vs+2**

Comment: Here is the answer you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021836/should-i-develop-with-cakephp-2-or-3/28025471#28025471